# mod_rewrite htaccess issues

Tags: .htaccess, seo, redirect

I have this site: neotel2000.com that works this way:

- Spanish language: neotel2000.com
- English language: neotel2000.com/en/
- French language: neotel2000.com/fr/

OK.

I need this:

I want that every possible section relative to the French version (/fr/), it will redirect (301) to the root domain (neotel2000.com). Example:

neotel2000.com/fr/whatever/  ----->  neotel2000.com

Although, there are some exceptions (i.e. there are 7 urls relatives to /fr/ where the 301 redirect should not apply) I'll show you one of these url exceptions:

https://www.neotel2000.com/fr/standard-virtuel/

So far I´ve searched dozens of psots here and other forums with no luck.

Here my .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !^GET\ ./https://www.neotel2000.com/fr/.*\ HTTP
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !^GET\ ./https://www.neotel2000.com/fr/standard-virtuel/.*\ HTTP
RewriteRule ^fr(.+)/ / [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Thank you loads

Answer (score 1):

You can use this rule

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/fr/(standard-virtuel|example2|example3)/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^fr(/.*)?$ / [R=301,L]
```

Just replace `example2`, `example3`, ... by what you want, each one separated by `|`

Or, if you prefer the longest version (not condensated), where each condition is for a specific url

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/fr/standard-virtuel/ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/fr/example2/ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/fr/example3/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^fr(/.*)?$ / [R=301,L]
```

Comment: It did not work. Neither the first nor the second rule. Any other suggestions? Thank you

Comment: Well, it should. The problem must lies elsewhere. Make sure that `mod_rewrite` is enabled and `.htaccess` files allowed. Also, do you have other rules ? Do you use a CMS or is it a custom website ?

Comment: Also, it seems to be working as expected on your website. Just tried `/fr/standard-virtuel/` and it is available, while `/fr/whatever/` is being redirected to home. If you don't see the same result, try clearing your browser cache and try again

Comment: "Make sure that mod_rewrite is enabled" <- It is enabled.
".htaccess files allowed" <- It is all correct here.

Comment: Here you have my all of my rules:

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
#
Options +FollowSymlinks
#
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
#

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/fr/(standard-virtuel|https://www.neotel2000.com/fr/les-cloud-call-center-permettent-aux-entreprises-deconomiser-largent-et-beaucoup/)/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^fr(/.*)?$ / [R=301,L]

</IfModule>

Comment: "Do you use a CMS or is it a custom website ?" <- WordPress

"Also, it seems to be working as expected on your website. Just tried /fr/standard-virtuel/ and it is available, while /fr/whatever/ is being redirected to home. If you don't see the same result, try clearing your browser cache and try again" <- Really weird. But try now if you don't mind. I already cleared cache in both, WordPress and CDN.

Comment: Your rule syntax is wrong. From your 2-exceptions rule example, it should be `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/fr/(standard-virtuel|les-cloud-call-center-permettent-aux-entreprises-deconomiser-largent-et-beaucoup)/ [NC]`. Since your exception links seem big, feel free to use second solution for readability. Also, from my experience with WordPress, it can quickly become a mess when trying to rewrite with htaccess instead of using its built-in rewrite system.